# MS Build version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem with MS build version. I have an existing solution with multiple .Net framework projects, to that solution I added a new .Net Core project. Now am getting an error in MS Build version (i.e: .Net framework requires MS build version 14.0 but .Net core requires MS build version 15.0). I can't able to choose build version for each project since that is a solution level setting. Is it possible to create different project's of the framework(.Net framework and .Net core) in a single solution? I am using Jet brains Rider as my IDE.

Comment: MSBuild doesn't play nice with mixed full framework and .NET Core projects in the same solution, from my experience. I'd recommend keeping separate solutions instead. If you need to share code between projects in different solutions, you can generate NuGet packages.

Comment: I will check with tat thank u :-)

Comment: I have mixed .Net Framework and .Net Core projects in one solution and it works just fine (using MSBuild 15.0 both from command line and within Visual Studio 2017). Why do you think .Net framework requires MSBuild 14? MSBuild 15 should handle it as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the IDE am using is jet brains rider. If I choose the MS build 14.0 .Net core application is not getting loaded and vice versa if i choose MS build 15.0. I haven't tried in visual studio.